# Unknown SQL Exception 300 occurred. VIEW SERVER STATE permission was denied on object 'server', database 'master'

Tags: 2016

I prepared New SP 2016 Farm with 4 Servers
App1 - MinRole (Application + Search)
App2 - Distributed Cache
WFE1 - Custom Role (Running Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web Application)
WFE2 - Custom Role (Running Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web Application)

In App1 below error keep throwing every time.
Unknown SQL Exception 300 occurred. Additional error information from SQL Server is included below.

VIEW SERVER STATE permission was denied on object 'server', database 'master'.
The user does not have permission to perform this action.